# CurrentCulture is ignored in DateTime.TryParse() C# MVC3 web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, formatting, regional

Even though i have

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" requestEncoding="utf-8" />
```

in web.config 
`DateTime.TryParse`, without passing CultureInfo, is ignoring my current Culture .

Application is a C# MVC3 web application.

Is there any solution for this.

Comment: MSDN says that TryParse should use current culture info. Can you give us an example of incorrect parsing? Also you can use TryParseExact - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx , if it can be a solution for you.

Comment: Now I understand,  that the web.config for the MVC application is not applied, to the child aspx web application. Once I modified the web.config in the aspx application folder it works fine. Thank you for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

@Smileek right, but you always can try something like this

```
DateTime dateResult;
dateString = "03/01/2009 10:00 AM";
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
DateTime.TryParse(dateString, culture, styles, out dateResult);
```